# ffmpeg prepend still image to video

Tags: ffmpeg, video, concatenation

Disclaimer: I am NOT proficient in video editing at all; this is almost my first attempt
so I could be missing something very basic. Please be lenient and redirect me to relevant
tutorials, if needed.

I tried searching and my (failed) attempts are the result.

I have a `.mp4` video:

```
  Stream #1:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 377 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 30k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : H.264/AVC video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : AVC Coding
  Stream #1:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 32000 Hz, mono, fltp, 126 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : AAC audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #1:2[0x3](eng): Data: bin_data (text / 0x74786574), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
```

And I need to prepend to it a "title" composed by a single `.png` image held for 15s.

I converted the image with:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i Cover.png -c:v libx264 -t 15 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=1920:1080 cover.mp4
```

getting a slightly different format (I suspect this is the cause of my problems):

```
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 195 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 libx264
```

I tried several different strategies to concatenate (possibly without re-encoding,
of course) the two files, but:

```
ffmpeg -i cover.mp4 -i video.mp4 -c copy out.mp4
```

Produces a video with the fixed cover image for the whole duration of the track, but audio dutifully starts after 15s.

```
echo file cover.mp4  >out.lst
echo file video.mp4 >>out.lst
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i out.lst -c copy out.mp4
```

Produces a garbled video (I see a "correct" I-frame, but immediately thereafter image gets garbled: all green and some "diff noise"); audio is ok.

```
ffmpeg -i cover.mp4 -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [vv] [aa]" -map "[vv]" -map "[aa]" out.mp4
```

Complains about missing audio stream in `cover.mp4` and I was unable to find the right spell to skip it.

What am I missing?

Comment: You cannot concat in copy mode if the two videos were not encoded using the same parameters. Encoder alone is not enough. You need to encode your video using the same parameters you used to convert the image. You can then concat in copy mode with no further encoding.

Comment: @Sark: Thanks. I suspected that much, but my specific problem is somewhat the reverse: I have the long encoded video I would like to avoid re-encoding (it was generated by Zoom and I have limited control over it's encoding); OTOH I can re-generate the image at will... if I manage to divine what are the right parameters to use. How can I extract the right parameters from the encoded video stream and use them to encode the still image? I tried to find the right parameters bur I didn't get there. Amy help would be welcome, of course.

Comment: @Ziobyte...Herein lies the issue. Firstly, there are many default parameters applied by the encoder. Not just those you select. Also, Zoom may not have used the same encoder as ffmpeg, and even if it did, successfully determining all the parameters it used is highly unlikely. Concatenating differently encoded videos, without reencoding, may not be impossible, but it is rife with issues, as you have already discovered.